Getting splines to match from all view points
I am trying to model the tesla Model y 2021 version in fustion 360 using images and measurements found online. I have cropped all the pictures border to border of the vehicle and aligned everything together in fusion so that everything would work. I am still having trouble getting the lines to match up. Please refer to the pictures, anything helps! If you read this far, thanks a lot for even considering my issue.

front view works but will get messed up if i try to fix another view





Hi. Welcome to GDSE. CAD questions are off-topic here. Try Engineering Stack Exchange.

CAD questions as such are allowed but they need to relate to graphic design. So if you were to ask how to use CAD to prepare illustrations for instructionals etc etc. Then it might be ontopic. But asking how to use the CAD app like this is certainly offtopic. Though, thats not really the point. Why would you ask people who generally know nothing of your problem. It just reduces chances of getting an answer. While i have done this i feel like theres not enough info to go on to solve your problem in either case.

No fix. The drawings you have used seem to contain black curves as well at the seams of the separate parts as on the clearly visible surface ridges (which actually are quite tightly curved, but still smooth areas). I'm afraid they are only a minor part of what's needed to present the real surfaces.
We do not know how you have tried to find the 3D paths which are in accordance with the found 2D images. Thus we do not have any idea what's your error in attempts to make even the sparse curves to fit in 3D. You should reveal how you found the 3D coordinates of the points of the curves. I'm afraid you do NOT have used any systematic method to find the right 3D curves when their perpendicular projections are known.
If you used some exact systematic method to draw the 3D curves to fit, it's well possible that the top, rear, front and side views are not exactly perpendicular parallel projections. Or they may show here and there different details.
Possible reasons:

The images are made only to look fine without worrying do they present the vehicle geometry right and be compatible with each other

The images are intentionally made to be useless for reverse engineering.


User joojaa has added in his comment one more important thing. Many details are not visible in the given images from more than one direction, because they are behind other parts. To avoid it there should be available cross-sections or X-ray images.
The only way to get it surely right is to buy, steal, rent or borrow a real vehicle and to make a proper 3D tracing photogrammetrically or otherwise.

I think the reason is neither 1 or 2 but rater that the line he is trying to trace isn't entirely visible in all projections simultaneously. The edge he is trying to trace dips below what is visible in the projection because the object car is not entirely convex. Concave lines are a bit hard form two projections to solve.
